# Получение exe файла из Электрон

Tags: javascript, electron

Каким образом можно получить исполняемый файл с `electron`?

То есть, надо собрать `html`, `css` и `js` в один `.exe` файл, чтобы потом можно было запустить на любом ПК.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615837/how-to-compile-an-electron-application-to-a-exe

Comment: в моём вчерашнем ответе-приложении есть и сборка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1227167