# Как собрать electron приложение для платформы windows в Linux?

Tags: node.js, electron

У меня есть electron приложение.
Операционная система Linux.
Для того что бы собрать приложение я использую `electron-forge`

В поле `makers` я указал все платформы. Меня интересует в основном `windows`.
Но когда я начинаю собирать приложение `npm run make` у меня оно собирается только под Linux.

Где или как мне указать, что мне нужно собрать приложение под `windows` ?

```
✔ Checking your system
✔ Resolving Forge Config
We need to package your application before we can make it
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
Making for the following targets: deb, rpm
✔ Making for target: deb - On platform: linux - For arch: x64
✔ Making for target: rpm - On platform: linux - For arch: x64
```

Мой `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "words",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "words",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/zababurinsv/words.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zababurinsv/words/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/zababurinsv/words#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-wix": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "electron": "^11.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "words"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-wix",
          "config": {
            "language": 1033,
            "manufacturer": "My Awesome Company"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: я смотрел в сторону electron-forge где-то полгода назад и не стал его использовать, имхо, это какой-то абстрактный инструмент для написания конкретных кейсов, я не увидел способа использовать его как "сел и поехал". если ты не привязан к electron-forge то рассмотри использование https://www.electron.build/ - хороший, умный инструмент, который умеет всё. я применяю его с 2016 года и он становится всё лучше. пример его использования есть в моём ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1227167

Comment: Я собрал уже приложение. Я посмотрел то что вы предложили. Там видимо не совсем то, что мне требовалось.
Я просто установил mono, wine,    electron-builder   и запустил комманду  "dist": "electron-builder  --windows".

А есть ли возможность уменьшить размер приложения  ? Любое приложение под electron насколько я понял занимает порядка 400 мб

Comment: уменьшение приложения - это упаковка в asar и разумное распределение модулей между dependencies и devDependencies. других способов я не нашёл