# Запустить проект без интернета, и установок. Node. Js

Tags: node.js, webpack, visual-studio-code, portability

Есть проект с webpack, babel, jest, eslint. Есть рабочий ПК без доступа к интернету, и нельзя установить ни какое по, в том числе node.js. Я нашёл node portable и VS code portable но как их теперь подружить? На флешке есть VS port, node port, и проект с скачанными нод модулями.  Нода такая https://github.com/garethflowers/nodejs-portable/

Comment: решением может стать сборка приложения на electron

Comment: Не могли бы по подробнее описать как это можно реализовать? Я погуглил electron это же фреймворк, для его работы тоже нужен node.

Comment: нет, node.js нужен для разработки, а после build-а он сам в себе несёт node.js и не нуждается при запуске ни в чём. я для SO делал [пример приложения](https://github.com/norbornen/electron-terminal-command-wrapper), можете клонировать репу, запустить `build:windows` и попробовать запустить приложение с флешки

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1227167/2659

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ, но мы не поняли друг друга. Мне надо, работатть над проектом дома, в нормальных условиях(VS code, webpack) , а потом принести его на работу (на флешке), и продолжить разработку (VS code, webpack и др). Работаю в гос организации и бывает свободное время для этого.

Comment: а. посмотрите в сторону https://replit.com/